# C# how to deal with callback function

Tags: c#, parsing, callback

```
  public User Login(User user)
    {
        User responseUser = null; ;
        parse.Users.Login<User>("hello", "99999", r =>
            {
                if (r.Success) { responseUser = r.Data; }
            });
        return responseUser;
    }
```

Why return responseUser is null but r.Data is not null?  Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't told us how the `parse.Users.Login<User>` function works but it seems that it is asynchronous. This means that it will return immediately and the callback called much later. So you will return null from the main function.

You need to modify the Login function so that it works with a callback as well:

```
public void Login(User user, Action<User> action)
{
    User responseUser = null;
    parse.Users.Login<User>("hello", "99999", r =>
    {
        if (r.Success) 
        { 
            action(r.Data);
        }
        else
        {
            action(null);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The Login function is third party API, i can't modify it

Comment: Then I am afraid that there's not much you could do about it. You are calling an asynchronous method inside it and you cannot possibly expect to have the result immediately. There's a hack by using `ManualResetEvent` to block the main thread while the asynchronous call is running but that's so much horrible that I won't even bother providing an example as it is a completely wrong approach. Ping me if you want to see this solution after all.